# iPhone mapview will only update when in wifi

Tags: ios4, mkmapview, wifi, zooming, 3g

I have a little application in progress. 
One of my current problems is: it seems that the MapView will only load map data when I am in wifi range (when e.g. zooming in). When only 3G/2G is available, it displays the tiles already cached but will not load new ones. It seems to be no problem with the general setup of my iPhone: the Maps application works nicley.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do other mapping-enabled apps work fine as well over 3G?  Are you certain that data is flowing over the 3G connection with other apps, and only your code is having a problem?  What about when you compile Apple's samples?

Comment: I have noticed this on my iPhone4 and 3Gs no idea what really is causing it, could be because of a slow 3G/2G connection. Try moving to a new region on the map then move back. Make sure 3G/2G connection is on, try other map based Apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... well, looks like I was indeed too impatient. Sometimes, it takes a lot of time until the maps starts loading.